# flutter: Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<Post>'

Tags: json, flutter

```
class Services {
  static const String url = 'urlllllllllllllllll';

  static Future<List<Post>> getPosts() async {
    try {
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final List<Post> listPosts = **Post.fromJson(response.body)**;
        return listPosts;
      } else {
        return <Post>[];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return <Post>[];
    }
  }
}
```

Two errors appear to run this source. (**)

1. A value of type 'Post' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List'.
   Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List'.
   2.The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'.

I just can't figure it out. I ask for your help.

Comment: Post.fromJson will return a single Post object, not a list. Simply try ````final List<Post> listPosts = [Post.fromJson(response.body)];````

Comment: On your second isssue - you are not parsing your response.body, so the full solution is: ````final List<Post> listPosts = [Post.fromJson(jsonParse(response.body))];````